# Sql Server 2016: Enable TLS 1.2 for SQL Server Connection

Tags: java, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2016, tls1.2

I've `SQL server 2016` running on `windows 2012 R2` and I applied the patch for TLSv1.2 support and rebooted the VM, https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3135244/tls-1-2-support-for-microsoft-sql-server I do see TLS 1.2 being enabled using `IISCrypto` tool on the SQL Server VM

We have Java 8 web application and we've forced the web application to use only TLS1.2 using JVM argument `-Djdk.tls.client.protocols="TLSv1.2"` (If I remove this JVM argument application connects to sql server fine), but we are seeing below error though `TLSv1.2` is enabled for SQL server

```
org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "Server chose TLSv1, but that protocol version is not enabled or not supported by the client.". ClientConnectionId:7564b6a1-60c0-4a24-8baa-7bd21f9512cf)
```

We also have a `.Net 2.0` windows service (only TLSv1.2 is enabled in registry) which is also failing to connect to `SQL Server 2016`

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: [DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (SECCreateCredentials()).]SSL Security error.
at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionInternal..ctor(OleDbConnectionString constr, OleDbConnection connection)
at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection.Open()
```

But if I enable SSL3 and TLS1.0 in the registry, `.Net 2.0` windows service connects to SQL Server 2016 fine.

I suspect, the issue is SQL Server not using `TLSv1.2` though `TLSv1.2` is enabled on the SQL Server VM, Can someone please help me if there anymore config or patches needs to be applied for SQL Server to support `TLSv1.2` ?

Comment: That link you refer to says you have to have 1.0 and 1.1 disabled in the registry for the server in order for 1.2 to work.  Rather than using the IISCrypto tool why don't you check the actual registry settings for the server and verify 1.0 and 1.1 are disabled and 1.2 is enabled?

Comment: @RanPaul Could you please try the approach given in my answer below and let me know if it works? Thanks in advance..

Comment: @RanPaul, Is there an answer already?

Answer (score 5):

Microsoft Windows Server stores information about different security-enhanced channel protocols that Windows Server supports. This information is stored in the following registry key:

> HKey_Local_Machine\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols

Typically, this key contains the following subkeys:

> PCT 1.0, SSL 2.0, SSL 3.0, TLS 1.0 ...

Each key holds information about the protocol for the key. Any one of these protocols can be enabled at the server. To do this, you create a new DWORDvalue in the server subkey of the protocol. You set the DWORDvalue to "1".

Important: Back up the registry before you modify it. Then, you can restore the registry if a problem occurs.

To enable the TLS 1.x protocol follow these steps:

Click Start, click Run, type regedt32 or type regedit, and then click OK.
In Registry Editor, locate the following registry key:

> HKey_Local_Machine\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders \SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.x\Server

On the Edit menu, click Add Value.
In the Data Type list, click DWORD.
In the Value Name box, type Enabled, and then click OK.

Note If this value is present, double-click the value to edit its current value.

Type 11111111 in Binary Editor to set the value of the new key equal to "1".
Click OK. Restart the computer.

Answer (score 3):

Check the involved certificates. One may be invalid.

If the machines validate their certificates, try:

Registry Script for disabling stupid encryptions:
Save this as .reg

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\SSL 2.0\Client]
"Enabled"=dword:00000000
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000001
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\SSL 2.0\Server]
"Enabled"=dword:00000000
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000001
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\SSL 3.0\Client]
"Enabled"=dword:00000000
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000001
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\SSL 3.0\Server]
"Enabled"=dword:00000000
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000001
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.0\Client]
"Enabled"=dword:00000000
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000001
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.0\Server]
"Enabled"=dword:00000000
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000001
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.1\Client]
"Enabled"=dword:00000000
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000001
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.1\Server]
"Enabled"=dword:00000000
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000001
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Client]
"Enabled"=dword:00000001
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000000
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Server]
"Enabled"=dword:00000001
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319]
"SchUseStrongCrypto"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319]
"SchUseStrongCrypto"=dword:00000001
```

You'll have to adjust your .NET Framework. If you are actually using .Net 2.0 (old!) the last two Keys should be

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v2.0.50727]
"SystemDefaultTlsVersions"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v2.0.50727]
"SystemDefaultTlsVersions"=dword:00000001
```

Here is a .ps1 by Chris Duck to check enabled encryptions

```
    <#
 .DESCRIPTION
   Outputs the SSL protocols that the client is able to successfully use to connect to a server.

 .NOTES

   Copyright 2014 Chris Duck
   http://blog.whatsupduck.net

   Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
   you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
   You may obtain a copy of the License at

     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

   Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
   distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
   WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
   See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
   limitations under the License.

 .PARAMETER ComputerName
   The name of the remote computer to connect to.

 .PARAMETER Port
   The remote port to connect to. The default is 443.

 .EXAMPLE
   Test-SslProtocols -ComputerName "www.google.com"

   ComputerName       : www.google.com
   Port               : 443
   KeyLength          : 2048
   SignatureAlgorithm : rsa-sha1
   Ssl2               : False
   Ssl3               : True
   Tls                : True
   Tls11              : True
   Tls12              : True
 #>
 function Test-SslProtocols {
   param(
     [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
     $ComputerName,

     [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
     [int]$Port = 443
   )
   begin {
     $ProtocolNames = [System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols] | gm -static -MemberType Property | ?{$_.Name -notin @("Default","None")} | %{$_.Name}
   }
   process {
     $ProtocolStatus = [Ordered]@{}
     $ProtocolStatus.Add("ComputerName", $ComputerName)
     $ProtocolStatus.Add("Port", $Port)
     $ProtocolStatus.Add("KeyLength", $null)
     $ProtocolStatus.Add("SignatureAlgorithm", $null)

     $ProtocolNames | %{
       $ProtocolName = $_
       $Socket = New-Object System.Net.Sockets.Socket([System.Net.Sockets.SocketType]::Stream, [System.Net.Sockets.ProtocolType]::Tcp)
       $Socket.Connect($ComputerName, $Port)
       try {
         $NetStream = New-Object System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream($Socket, $true)
         $SslStream = New-Object System.Net.Security.SslStream($NetStream, $true)
         $SslStream.AuthenticateAsClient($ComputerName,  $null, $ProtocolName, $false )
         $RemoteCertificate = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2]$SslStream.RemoteCertificate
         $ProtocolStatus["KeyLength"] = $RemoteCertificate.PublicKey.Key.KeySize
         $ProtocolStatus["SignatureAlgorithm"] = $RemoteCertificate.SignatureAlgorithm.FriendlyName
         $ProtocolStatus["Certificate"] = $RemoteCertificate
         $ProtocolStatus.Add($ProtocolName, $true)
       } catch  {
         $ProtocolStatus.Add($ProtocolName, $false)
       } finally {
         $SslStream.Close()
       }
     }
     [PSCustomObject]$ProtocolStatus
   }
 }
```